# Easy to use 3D Environment in Java

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, interactive

How might i go about a 3D Environment in Java? I want to suspend balls in space like this: [3D ScatterPlot](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Scatter_plot.jpg). I presume i should find a library that supports this, but are there libraries already made for placing basic shapes, where i can tell the library i want spheres at (x,y,z) with r radius, and i will instantly be able to see this, being able to drag around the camera and zoom with scroll wheel? Would i have to program most of it almost entirely on my own, down to where the spheres would move if i rotate the camera on each axis?

Is [Java 3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html) a good way to start, or are there other better libraries? I have plenty enough experience drawing things on 2D using image buffers and either displaying on screen or saving to a file, but going 3D and allowing you to fly around and zoom in/out to see details on a (micro/macro)-scopic scale seems like an extreme step! I do only want to suspend spheres though, which i hope simplifies the issue, if only a little!

Comment: Personally, I would go for a more dedicated library then is available from Oracle.  You could also investigate JavaFX/Java8 which has 3D support now built in.  Ease of use is subjective and is going to require you, at any level, to have some concept of 3D graphics principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 3D is one of the most high-level APIs available for 3D in Java and will probably require the least amount of coding to get something up and running.  **However**, the project has long since been abandoned.  I don't think there has been any effort to maintain the project in the past half-decade (let alone advance it) and you may find it difficult to find current online tutorials or online help.

You may want to look into a more modern 3D API:

JavaFX -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/shape3d.htm#CJAHFAHA

jMonkey -- http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_simpleapplication

Or to go lower level, JOGL: http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jogl/

Personally, I feel JOGL is the best choice.  The learning curve is higher, but since you are working with standard OpenGL APIs, any knowledge you gain is easily portable to other platforms.

Comment: Looking first glance at your javaFX link, it looks pretty nice, at least defining the shapes are as simple as i wanted it. This question is only intended to ask where i ought to start, so i will do some research into your three options. Thanks!

Comment: So far i tried to look into JOGL, and there are a couple good tutorials on this, but they reference JOGL versions that are out of date, so the code doesnt work. Hopefully ill have better luck/documentation with your other suggestions! :)